# Proper to use HTML 5 section element as content between header and footer?

Tags: html, semantics

I've read [conflicting](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) [webpages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) about using HTML 5's `section` element. Is it semantically appropriate to use it as the section between my header and footer?

```
<body>
  <header>logo, nav links</header>
  <section>main content of my webpage</section>
  <footer>copyright, more links, contact info</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Myself, I would wrap SECTION in ARTICLE.

Comment: @Diodeus - so you would make the main content of the webpage an article?

Comment: I would, but you can have multiple articles per page as well.

Comment: I would **not** make the main content of a page an article.  Article ought to be used for self-contained blocks of content that could be syndicated.

Comment: @KatieK: There are many cases where the main content would be appropriate for `article`. Think of a page containing a blog post.

Comment: @Diodeus: Wrapping `article` in `section`: in many cases this would result in a wrong outline; it would be only correct for some cases, for example a page listing recent blog postings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start is Bruce Lawson's [Scooby Doo and the proposed HTML5 `<content>` element](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/scooby-doo-content-element/) .

You'll find a link in there to the [opinion of Ian (Hixie) Hickson](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Aug/0298.html) who is the editor of the WHATWG version of HTML5 (aka HTML Living Standard) and until recently editor of the W3C version of the HTML5 standard.

What he says (and has consistently said for at least the last 5 years) is that there is no need for a sectioning element there. If you need a containing element for everything that is not in the header or footer `<div>` is the element to use.

On the other hand, another member of the W3C HTML working group, Steve Faulkner, has proposed the [`<maincontent>`](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/maincontent.html) element for your use case, on the grounds that is allows the ARIA "main" role to be incorporated into native HTML.

FWIW, for me, it seems odd that you should have a special element for between the header and footer in `<body>` but not for between header and footer in `<section>` or `<article>` so I'm with Hixie on this.

I also don't buy [Steve's comments](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/scooby-doo-content-element/#comment-1017996) that it will be useful in that it will mark the main content even if the other sectioning and header/footer elements are not marked up correctly, since there doesn't seem any case in which I could advocate its use. It seems to be only for the web author who wants to do a half-assed job.

Do note that if `<maincontent>` does get accepted, it will not be part of HTML5. The earliest it could appear would be HTML 5.1

Answer (score 1):

`<section>` is slightly more semantic than `<div>`.  One of `<section>`'s main points for HTML5 is that it helps the browser to understand the document's [outline](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/).

Your approach is really dependent on the content of our page.  Is everything in between the `<header>` and `<footer>` tightly related, or could it be broken down a little into more `<sections>`, or even other elements?

There will always be sources full of conflicting advice, especially for something in the development and utilization stage that HTML5 is in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using headings (`h1` to `h6`), you are already using something that could be called "implicit sections". The **outlines** of the following two markup examples **semantically identical**:

Example 1:

```
<body>
  <header>
   <h1>My cool site</h1>
   …
  </header>
  <section>
   <h1>My cool article</h1>
   …
  </section>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

Example 2:

```
<body>
  <header>
   <h1>My cool site</h1>
   …
  </header>

  <h2>My cool article</h2>
   …

  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

So in this very case it wouldn't matter if you explicitly add `section` or not: the outline (the semantic structure) would be the same. Side note: it is [recommended](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/headings-and-sections.html#headings-and-sections) to always explicitly use the sectioning elements for sectioning content:

> Authors are also encouraged to explicitly wrap sections in elements of sectioning content, instead of relying on the implicit sections generated by having multiple headings in one element of sectioning content.

(however, this applies only for sectioning content, not sectioning roots (like `body`))

Now, your question can't be answered generally, if we don't know which headings you are using. There are cases which would require you to use `section` (or `article`), otherwise you would get a wrong outline for your page. And there are cases where the use of an explicit `section` (or `article`) is optional.

Some general tips (applicable to "prototypical" websites only; there are of course many exceptions; these tips should only give you an idea)

- each page of your site should have a **site heading** (e.g. "John's blog") *and* a **content heading** (e.g. "I found a funny video")

  - the site heading is the first heading in `body`, which is not included in a sectioning element (`section`, `article`, `nav` or `aside`)
- the site heading "dominates" all scopes of your page, e.g. in most cases a) the navigation and b) the content
- all scopes of your page should have a heading (you can visually hide them with CSS, though). If you can't or don't want to give a heading to a scope, you *have* to use a sectioning element (`section`, `article`, `nav` or `aside`), which would create an untitled/implicit heading